# Copy Wave Dataset from one account to another

Tags: salesforce

I have Wave dataset in production with some orders updated. I need to copy the same from UAT environment to Production.
These are separated accounts.
How can I copy the dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way would be to log into your test account with DataLoader and export the those records. Then login to Dataloader with your production site and UPSERT those records back to the object. That would update the records in production.

Comment: Hey Nelsons, Sorry for the late reply and thanks for your response. However, the number of records here was 52M. So, could not do that.